# When I set the HTML data to TextView it contains a white space at the beginning of every paragraph. How do I remove that whitespace?

Tags: android, html

I want to display `HTML` data to `TextView`.

When I set the `HTML` data, the `TextView` contains a white space at the beginning of every paragraph.

How do I remove those whitespaces?

```
descriptionTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(StaticData.newsList.get(position).getDescription()));
```

Here's my activity:

[image]

Comment: can you provide an example of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try trim()

```
descriptionTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(StaticData.newsList.get(position).getDescription()).toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
descriptionTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(StaticData.newsList.get(position).getDescription().trim()));
```

It should remove any leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: Maybe `descriptionTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(StaticData.newsList.get(position).getDescription()).trim());` would work

Comment: descriptionTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(StaticData.newsList.get(position).getDescription()).toString().trim());
this will work but it removes the bold/italic effects.

Answer (score 0):

`descriptionTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(StaticData.newsList.get(position).getDescription()).toString().trim());` this will work but it removes the inside the image also  not loading

Answer (score 0):

trim or ant other string function will effect the entire text. you have to analyze the text and remove the tags and white tags only at the beginning of the string. if you share the html that would help